# TCP send-Q mysteriously full on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, tcp, queue

Something weird is happening to my system: TCP connection will hang after about 60kB of data transfer, netstat shows that:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
tcp4       0 268680  192.168.0.77.http      192.168.0.77.49221     ESTABLISHED
```

or if the server quits, it shows:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
tcp4       0 635920  192.168.0.77.xsync     192.168.0.77.49362     FIN_WAIT_1
```

This only happens when i try to connect to the IP of my computer.

- If I use localhost/127.0.0.1, there is no problem.
- I can connect to any other IP on the Internet without a problem, and surf the net freely
- More interesting is, people in the same LAN can connect to me and work without problem (using HTTP, TCP).

It looks like the send-Q is full, but I really could not find out why. Please can somebody help me solve this problem.

Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: So...  60kB is received by the client but the remaining 630kB (approx) are never seen?  A network trace (tcpdump, wireshark, etc.) would be helpful.